# polynomial_trend attribute of the SARIMAXResults object doesn't contain the fitted trend polynomial coefficients

Tags: python, statsmodels

I use python's statsmodels package to fit a seasonal ARIMA model.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

data = pd.Series([7.08, 6.53, 6.82, 7.32, 8.67, 8.54, 8.99, 9.78], index=pd.date_range('2005-06-30', '2007-03-31', freq='Q'))
# seasonal random walk with drift
order = (0,0,0) 
seasonal_order = (0,1,0,4)
m = sm.tsa.SARIMAX(endog=data, order=order, seasonal_order=seasonal_order, freq='Q', trend= 'ct')
result = m.fit()
```

According to the documentation, the `polynomial_trend` contains trend polynomial coefficients, but after fitting the model, `result.polynomial_trend` equals `array([1, 1], dtype=int32)`. Is this a bug? By the way, I can get the fitted coefficients by `result.params`. It just doesn't show in the `polynomial_trend` attribute.